# What courses/branches of math directly build upon calc III? (Measure Theory, Lebesgue-Integral, Stokes, ...)

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

I took calculus III in my 3rd semester and it was my favorite course so far by a lot. This term I chose complex analysis, topology and PDEs, though could not find any course that seemed to be a direct successor to calc III. Is that simply the "end of the road" for general calculus and anything beyond that branches out?
Next semester I will be able to pick courses that dive into differential geometry which I expect/hope to build further upon the theory but I would be interested to hear what fields of math or undergrad courses usually most directly follow up on the topics of calc III.

Comment: Differential geometry of manifolds, in particular, Lie groups theory

Comment: Indeed, on this kind of course you will also learn integration on manifolds, and will learn a single [formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem) which generalizes Green's theorem, Stokes' theorem and the Divergence theorem!

Comment: @Gérard Are you satisfied with your question considering the comments and the answer or were you looking for something different?

Comment: @SonGohan a mixture of waiting to see whether more people would like to elaborate and being busy with uni stuff. I accepted your answer which definitely got me interested in differential geometry/topology more (depending on how much I will like my introductionary topology course, but from the very little I know so far I think I'll like the field)

Comment: Do not worry, happy to help! :) If you have any other question, just stop here or ask on the site! good luck with the courses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in “vector calculus” that you studied in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the natural generalization is in ambient that are not (fully) Euclidean, like manifolds. Then, together with the notions you’ll be studying in general topology, you will find all the calc 3 tools in *differential topology.* Just as a small reference to feel the continuity of these topics: check Vector Analysis by Klaus Jänich.

Then one can decide to take a more geometric approach, studying differential forms from geometric view point, with complex geometry as well with theories like [Dolbeaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolbeault_cohomology). On the contrary, you can approach manifolds and differential forms from the analytic point of view, adding a particular "scalar product" on the manifold you are studying and defining on it all the differential operator of calc 3 (gradient, divergence, curl, laplacian,...) and studying PDEs on manifolds (like the heat equation on a torus with two holes, and so on). You can have REAL FUN in either direction!